# Self made exception shows up way later when exit() is called. Again

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here are the parts of my code that could have something to do with the problem: (I cut away as much as possible)

```
import os
import getpass

def PAUSE():
    input("= Press <ENTER> to continue...")

def clearscreen():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

def loginscreen():
    clearscreen()
    print("==================================================================")
    print("=                              LOGIN                             =")
    print("==================================================================")
    print("= None Important.                                                =")
    print("==================================================================")
    username = input("= Please enter your username: ")
    password = getpass.getpass("= Please enter the password that belongs to that username: ")
    print("==================================================================")
    try:
        # I had too cut away the MariaDB Section for a MCVE, and thus i had to fill the dbusername and sdbpassword and isadmin, but without modifying relevant code. Thus i might have made a mistake in this array, dont use them alot sooo... if this were to occur i am sorry....
        ['dbusername = "stackoverflow", dbpassword = "stackoverflow", isadmin = "No"']
        for row in results:
            dbusername = row[0]
            dbpassword = row[1]
            isadmin = row [2]
            if username == dbusername:
                if password == dbpassword:
                    if isadmin == "Yes":
                        admin_main_menu()
                    elif isadmin == "No":
                        clearscreen()
                        main_menu()
########## For some reason the same problem arises when i use the commented away code under this comment.
#        clearscreen()
#        print("==============================================")
#        print("=         Unkown Username / Password         =")
#        print("==============================================")
#        PAUSE()
#        print("==============================================")
#        loginscreen()
    except:
        clearscreen()
        print("Failed to check codes. (Error: 5646FCJU), Contact N.S. Geldorp")
        PAUSE()       

def main_menu():
    clearscreen()
    print("=============================================")
    print("=                 Main Menu                 =")
    print("=============================================")
    print("= 1. All unimportant...                     =")
    print("= 5. Exit                                   =")
    print("=============================================")
    answer = input("= Please enter the number of the function you wish to use: ")
    print("=============================================")
    clearscreen()
    if answer == "1":
#        print_animals()
        print("Not needed")
        PAUSE()
    elif answer == "5":
#        pass
        print("Exiting...")
        exit()
    else:
        print("Unimportant...")
        PAUSE()
        main_menu()
```

Now, I cut away everything but perhaps relevant parts of the login screen and the standard main menu. And of course the functions as PAUSE and clearscreen as they always reappear in relevant functions. At least if I wrote them. Now what happens is that when I have a successful login and I go to the menu, And I decide to exit, It shows me the error written in the except of the login screen... I don't get it, do you?

Comment: *What* exception? You haven't said what error you are talking about.

Comment: In the login section, there is a Try, and then a except. Thats the exception i mean...

Comment: No, that's where you're *catching* it. You haven't said what exception is *raised*.

Comment: I meant that that exception gets raised on screen when i call exit(), not a official error code, but the one i made myself

Comment: You're still failing to understand the differerence between an exception - which is something that is *raised* by your code - and the try/except code, which is the thing that *handles* it.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I am a beginner, anywhere you would recommend me to read about it? Could learn from it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is demonstration 1,442,633 of why you must never, ever use a blank `except` clause.

`sys.exit()` works by raising an exception: `SystemExit`. Normally, that exception bubbles all the way up to the interpreter, which catches it and exits gracefully. But because your try/except code catches *everything*, it catches that too; so you see your own error message instead of the interpreter quitting.

You should only ever catch the things that you know you can deal with. I'm not sure what exceptions you are expecting with that code, but presumably they are ones that are raised by the database code. You should work out which ones could be raised, and catch those only: for example, `except TypeError:`.

At the very least, you should restrict your except to only catch actual errors, which you can do with `except Exception:`; SystemExit descends from BaseException, which is the parent class of Exception which all other runtime errors descend from. But, you really shouldn't do that, you should catch the *specific* exceptions only.

(Note also, it makes no sense to have that for loop over the database results; I don't understand why you have done that.)

Comment: The for loop was an idea of my maths teacher (Who teaches me to code). And ill look into the except. But even before I had the except I had this problem. There was no except but I had the code which I now commented away. And it also happens if I use pass and not exit()...

Comment: Using a pokemon catcher at the top of your program isn't always bad. Maybe you want your program to exit gracefully even if you send it a ctrl-c or exit(), it is however often bad if you do not actually handle the exception and just continue running the program